# How to find the monthly return of stocks using data.table in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I have two months of data for two stocks as follows -

```
dt <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18718, 18722, 18723, 18724, 
                                  18725, 18726, 18729, 18730, 18731, 18732, 18733, 18736, 18737, 
                                  18738, 18739, 18740, 18743, 18744, 18745, 18746, 18747, 18750, 
                                  18751, 18752, 18753, 18754, 18757, 18758, 18759, 18760, 18761, 
                                  18764, 18765, 18766, 18767, 18768, 18771, 18772, 18773, 18774, 
                                  18778, 18718, 18722, 18723, 18724, 18725, 18726, 18729, 18730, 
                                  18731, 18732, 18733, 18736, 18737, 18738, 18739, 18740, 18743, 
                                  18744, 18745, 18746, 18747, 18750, 18751, 18752, 18753, 18754, 
                                  18757, 18758, 18759, 18760, 18761, 18764, 18765, 18766, 18767, 
                                  18768, 18771, 18772, 18773, 18774, 18778), class = "Date"), 
               close = c(123, 
                         125.9, 126.21, 127.9, 130.36, 132.995, 131.24, 134.43, 132.03, 
                         134.5, 134.16, 134.84, 133.11, 133.5, 131.94, 134.32, 134.72, 
                         134.39, 133.58, 133.48, 131.46, 132.54, 127.85, 128.1, 129.74, 
                         130.21, 126.85, 125.91, 122.77, 124.97, 127.45, 126.27, 124.85, 
                         124.69, 127.31, 125.43, 127.1, 126.9, 126.85, 125.28, 124.61, 
                         2137.75, 2225.55, 2224.75, 2249.68, 2265.44, 2285.88, 2254.79, 
                         2267.27, 2254.84, 2296.66, 2297.76, 2302.4, 2293.63, 2293.29, 
                         2267.92, 2315.3, 2326.74, 2307.12, 2379.91, 2429.89, 2410.12, 
                         2395.17, 2354.25, 2356.74, 2381.35, 2398.69, 2341.66, 2308.76, 
                         2239.08, 2261.97, 2316.16, 2321.41, 2303.43, 2308.71, 2356.09, 
                         2345.1, 2406.67, 2409.07, 2433.53, 2402.51, 2411.56), 
               ticker = c("AAPL", 
                          "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
                          "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
                          "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
                          "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
                          "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
                          "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", 
                          "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", 
                          "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", 
                          "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", 
                          "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", 
                          "GOOG")), row.names = c(NA, -82L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
                          ))
```

I want to find the monthly return of these stocks using only data.table. Is there any existing function or an easy way to accomplish this?

I have tried to solve it using the following code, but it is giving error -

```
dt[, return := rep(periodReturn(.SD, period = 'monthly', type = "arithmetic"), .N), by = .(ticker)]
```

Here is the error

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(return, rep(periodReturn(.SD, period = "monthly",  : 
  Supplied 82 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 41 in column 'return'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

Any insights will be helpful.

The expected output is

```
ticker  month   return
AAPL    4      0.06878049
AAPL    5      -0.05210710
GOOG    4      0.1274096597
GOOG    5      0.0005974806
```

Comment: I think you need to specify `length.out = .N`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, the error with size mismatch can be solved if we specify the `length.out` in `rep`

```
library(data.table)
library(quantmod)
dt[, return := rep(periodReturn(.SD, period = 'monthly', 
          type = "arithmetic"), length.out = .N), by = .(ticker)]
```

-output

```
dt
          date    close ticker        return
 1: 2021-04-01  123.000   AAPL  0.0687804878
 2: 2021-04-05  125.900   AAPL -0.0521071048
 3: 2021-04-06  126.210   AAPL  0.0687804878
 4: 2021-04-07  127.900   AAPL -0.0521071048
 5: 2021-04-08  130.360   AAPL  0.0687804878
 6: 2021-04-09  132.995   AAPL -0.0521071048
 7: 2021-04-12  131.240   AAPL  0.0687804878
 8: 2021-04-13  134.430   AAPL -0.0521071048
 9: 2021-04-14  132.030   AAPL  0.0687804878
10: 2021-04-15  134.500   AAPL -0.0521071048
11: 2021-04-16  134.160   AAPL  0.0687804878
12: 2021-04-19  134.840   AAPL -0.0521071048
13: 2021-04-20  133.110   AAPL  0.0687804878
14: 2021-04-21  133.500   AAPL -0.0521071048
15: 2021-04-22  131.940   AAPL  0.0687804878
16: 2021-04-23  134.320   AAPL -0.0521071048
17: 2021-04-26  134.720   AAPL  0.0687804878
18: 2021-04-27  134.390   AAPL -0.0521071048
19: 2021-04-28  133.580   AAPL  0.0687804878
20: 2021-04-29  133.480   AAPL -0.0521071048
21: 2021-04-30  131.460   AAPL  0.0687804878
22: 2021-05-03  132.540   AAPL -0.0521071048
23: 2021-05-04  127.850   AAPL  0.0687804878
24: 2021-05-05  128.100   AAPL -0.0521071048
25: 2021-05-06  129.740   AAPL  0.0687804878
26: 2021-05-07  130.210   AAPL -0.0521071048
27: 2021-05-10  126.850   AAPL  0.0687804878
28: 2021-05-11  125.910   AAPL -0.0521071048
29: 2021-05-12  122.770   AAPL  0.0687804878
30: 2021-05-13  124.970   AAPL -0.0521071048
31: 2021-05-14  127.450   AAPL  0.0687804878
32: 2021-05-17  126.270   AAPL -0.0521071048
33: 2021-05-18  124.850   AAPL  0.0687804878
34: 2021-05-19  124.690   AAPL -0.0521071048
35: 2021-05-20  127.310   AAPL  0.0687804878
36: 2021-05-21  125.430   AAPL -0.0521071048
37: 2021-05-24  127.100   AAPL  0.0687804878
38: 2021-05-25  126.900   AAPL -0.0521071048
39: 2021-05-26  126.850   AAPL  0.0687804878
40: 2021-05-27  125.280   AAPL -0.0521071048
41: 2021-05-31  124.610   AAPL  0.0687804878
42: 2021-04-01 2137.750   GOOG  0.1274096597
43: 2021-04-05 2225.550   GOOG  0.0005974806
44: 2021-04-06 2224.750   GOOG  0.1274096597
45: 2021-04-07 2249.680   GOOG  0.0005974806
46: 2021-04-08 2265.440   GOOG  0.1274096597
47: 2021-04-09 2285.880   GOOG  0.0005974806
48: 2021-04-12 2254.790   GOOG  0.1274096597
49: 2021-04-13 2267.270   GOOG  0.0005974806
50: 2021-04-14 2254.840   GOOG  0.1274096597
51: 2021-04-15 2296.660   GOOG  0.0005974806
52: 2021-04-16 2297.760   GOOG  0.1274096597
53: 2021-04-19 2302.400   GOOG  0.0005974806
54: 2021-04-20 2293.630   GOOG  0.1274096597
55: 2021-04-21 2293.290   GOOG  0.0005974806
56: 2021-04-22 2267.920   GOOG  0.1274096597
57: 2021-04-23 2315.300   GOOG  0.0005974806
58: 2021-04-26 2326.740   GOOG  0.1274096597
59: 2021-04-27 2307.120   GOOG  0.0005974806
60: 2021-04-28 2379.910   GOOG  0.1274096597
61: 2021-04-29 2429.890   GOOG  0.0005974806
62: 2021-04-30 2410.120   GOOG  0.1274096597
63: 2021-05-03 2395.170   GOOG  0.0005974806
64: 2021-05-04 2354.250   GOOG  0.1274096597
65: 2021-05-05 2356.740   GOOG  0.0005974806
66: 2021-05-06 2381.350   GOOG  0.1274096597
67: 2021-05-07 2398.690   GOOG  0.0005974806
68: 2021-05-10 2341.660   GOOG  0.1274096597
69: 2021-05-11 2308.760   GOOG  0.0005974806
70: 2021-05-12 2239.080   GOOG  0.1274096597
71: 2021-05-13 2261.970   GOOG  0.0005974806
72: 2021-05-14 2316.160   GOOG  0.1274096597
73: 2021-05-17 2321.410   GOOG  0.0005974806
74: 2021-05-18 2303.430   GOOG  0.1274096597
75: 2021-05-19 2308.710   GOOG  0.0005974806
76: 2021-05-20 2356.090   GOOG  0.1274096597
77: 2021-05-21 2345.100   GOOG  0.0005974806
78: 2021-05-24 2406.670   GOOG  0.1274096597
79: 2021-05-25 2409.070   GOOG  0.0005974806
80: 2021-05-26 2433.530   GOOG  0.1274096597
81: 2021-05-27 2402.510   GOOG  0.0005974806
82: 2021-05-31 2411.560   GOOG  0.1274096597
```

---

If we want to summarise, wrap it in a `list` as `xts` attribute built on top of `matrix` from `periodReturn` may need it to be blocked within a `list`.  When we use `rep`, it strips off the `xts/matrix` attribute and the resulting column is `numeric` `vector`

```
dt[, .(return = .(periodReturn(.SD, period = 'monthly',
       type = "arithmetic"))), .(ticker)]
   ticker                    return
1:   AAPL    0.06878049,-0.05210710
2:   GOOG 0.1274096597,0.0005974806
```

---

Or remove the `xts` attribute by converting to `numeric` and it should work

```
library(lubridate)
dt[, .(month = unique(month(date)), 
    return = as.numeric(periodReturn(.SD, period = 'monthly',
       type = "arithmetic"))), .(ticker)]
ticker month        return
1:   AAPL     4  0.0687804878
2:   AAPL     5 -0.0521071048
3:   GOOG     4  0.1274096597
4:   GOOG     5  0.0005974806
```

Comment: Thanks akrun! It does solved this issue. As, the result is repeated, I tried to summarize the result for each stock using following code - ```dt[, .(return = rep(periodReturn(.SD, period = 'monthly', type = "arithmetic"), length.out = .N)), by = .(ticker)]```, however I am getting error when I try to remove ```rep``` function.

Comment: @Saurabh Why do you need the `rep` if you are summarising

Comment: After removing ```rep```, I am getting error  - ```Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , .(return = periodReturn(.SD, period = "monthly",  : 
  All items in j=list(...) should be atomic vectors or lists. If you are trying something like j=list(.SD,newcol=mean(colA)) then use := by group instead (much quicker), or cbind or merge afterwards.```

Comment: @Saurabh it is because the lengths are different.  in both groups i..e `dt[, .(return = .(periodReturn(.SD, period = 'monthly', type = "arithmetic"))), .(ticker)]
   ticker                    return
1:   AAPL    0.06878049,-0.05210710
2:   GOOG 0.1274096597,0.0005974806
`

Comment: Thanks again @akrun. Do you know how I can show the out put in following format? ```ticker  month   return
AAPL    04      0.06878049
AAPL    05      -0.05210710
GOOG    04      0.1274096597
GOOG    05      0.0005974806``` Sorry, the output is messed up a bit in comments box.

Comment: @Saurabh can you please update in your post rather than in comments as I couldn't understand the format

Comment: Thank you so much @akrun!

Comment: it would be interesting to see base R formula for that so quantmod is not required